# scala Option mutually exclusive values

Tags: scala

I have an

```
val file: Option = xxxx
val request: Option = yyyyy
```

These are mutually exclusive so naturally a for comprehension is what I want.  Is there a clean way of

1. throwing validation exception if both are None
2. throwing validation exception if both are Some(x)
3. processing the one or the other

I am thinking maybe match on a tuple may be the cleanest but wondering if there is some map or flatMap recoverWith/rescue trickery that might look readable and simple.

Comment: Would it not be clearer to use an [Either](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.Either)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a pattern match, though it doesn't scale all that well for adding more options.

```
(file, request) match {
  case (Some(f), None) => // handle file
  case (None, Some(r)) => // handle request
  case (None, None) => // error case
  case (Some(_), Some(_)) => // error case
}
```

But if you can actually make "all None" the only error case and instead of erroring on more than one Some, you can easily put them in your preferred order and only work on the most important one that's not None -

```
// file is more important, ignore request unless file is None
Seq(file, request).flatten.headOption match {
  case Some(x) => // x is either file or request's value
  case None => // All None, error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's this:

```
val result = List(file, request).flatten
if (result.length != 1) throw(...) else [do something with result.head]
```

Or marginally cleaner:

```
List(file, request).flatten match { case x::Nil => x ; case _ => throw (...)}
```

But neither are a clear way of expressing your intent, so I'm not sure I'd recommend either.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't tricky enough to be simple and readable:

```
(x filter (_ => y.isEmpty)) orElse (y filter (_ => x.isEmpty)) orElse ???
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other responses suggest, I don't think there is a simple way. In this case I like to create a new de-constructor (unapply). It will make the intent clear and keep your code tidy.

```
object Xor {
  def unapply[T](p: (Option[T], Option[T])): Option[T] = p match {
    case (None, b @ Some(_)) => b
    case (a @ Some(_), None) => a
    case _ => None
  }
}

val file: Option[Int] = ???
val request: Option[Int] = ???
(file, request) match {
  case Xor(x) => // use x
  case _      => // error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to transform the 2 vals of file&request to an Either construct. To do it my preferred way is to use pattern matching as already suggested here by other users.

When you'll code receive an Either instead of 2 parameters you'll be sure that on only one of them exist and this will let you writing a more functional code.

After you have the Either you can use the .fold(handleFileFunc, handleReqFunc) method on it.

```
def handleFileFunc(f: File) = ???
def handleReqFunc(r: Request) = ???

val data: Either[File, Request] = ???

data fold (handleFileFunc, handleReqFunc)
```